# RAID6 will not reassemble with 2 failed disks

Tags: hard-drive, raid, mdadm

[Relevant photo album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njAQh.jpg)

Hello all. I have a file server running ubuntu 12.04 (See first picture) with 6x Seagate 3TB HDDs in a RAID 6 configuration (giving 12TB of storage). This is a software RAID, created from within the O/S.

Unfortunately, one of the disks failed, so I need to find out which one it is and replace it. I took the one I thought was failed out and plugged it into my windows machine, which formatted it to NTFS. This turned out to be a disk that was OK, however.

So now I have 2 drives missing (one failed, one reformatted). A RAID6 *should* be able to withstand 2 failed drives, so I am confused as to why I can't rebuild the array in its degraded state?

It won't start using the disk utility, and I can't get it to do anything if I run

```
sudo mdadm --assemble --scan
```

or

```
sudo mdadm --assemble /md/0
```

So I tried stopping the array using

```
sudo mdadm --stop /dev/md0
```

which is fine, and stops the array. So I tried assembling it using the 4 working drives:

```
sudo mdadm --assemble /dev/md0 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sde1 /dev/sdf1
```

to which I got the reply

```
mdadm: /dev/md/0 assembled from 1 drive - not enough to start the array
```

Any help gratefully received, and I am obviously happy to try to answer any questions you may have. Thanks in advance.